# Twilio messages not firing on cron lamba

Tags: node.js, serverless-framework, twilio-api, aws-serverless

I've been working on this issue for a few hours with no success.  I am triggering the below function to run every 15 minutes. I can see from the CloudWatch that the function is firing. From my logs, I know that the function successfully getting appointments that require notification be sent. I am using 2 try/catch blocks to try and get some error message coming through, but no errors are being logged.

When I run this function using `sls invoke local`,  it works fine and sends the expected text message to the correct numbers. However, when deployed and run on a cron-basis, its not working but also not erroring out - so I am at a loss.

I think it's an async/await issue. Basically, the console logs show up in the Cloudwatch logs, but nothing inside the `twilioClient.messages.create` function comes out in the logs.

Any help would be appreciated - I am sure it's something simple, but been staring at this for a few hours now without any success!

```
function sendNotifications(appointments) {
  console.log('require notifications', appointments.length);
  appointments.forEach(function(appointment) {
    // Create options to send the message
    // Appointments show in the logs
    console.log('appt', appointment);
    console.log('from', process.env.TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER);

    try {
      const options = {
        to: `${appointment.meta.contact.number}`,
        from: process.env.TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER,
        /* eslint-disable max-len */
        body: `Hi ${appointment.meta.contact.name}. Just a reminder that you have an property viewing for ${appointment.meta.property.name} at ${appointment.date}, ${appointment.time}. Please reply with CONFIRM to confirm that you'll be attending this viewing or CANCEL BOOKING to cancel this viewing.`
        /* eslint-enable max-len */
      };

      // Send the message! - this log displays
      console.log('about to send message');
      twilioClient.messages.create(options, function(err, response, callback) {
        // Nothing in this block gets printed to the logs
        if (err) {
          // Just log it for now
          console.log('ERROR', err);
        } else {
          // Log the last few digits of a phone number
          let masked = appointment.meta.contact.number.substr(
            0,
            appointment.meta.contact.number.length - 5
          );
          masked += '*****';
          console.log(`Message sent to ${masked}`);

          try {
            updateBooking({ booking: appointment, message: response });
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(e.message);
          }
        }

        // Don't wait on success/failure, just indicate all messages have been
        // queued for delivery
        if (callback) {
          callback.call();
        }
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('ERR', e.message, appointment);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the doc https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/quickstart/node

`twilioClient.messages.create` does not have a callback params, but returns a Promise

Try to execute the Lambda with:

```
twilioClient.messages
  .create({
     body: 'just for test',
     from: 'a verified number',
     to: 'a verified number'
   })
  .then(message => console.log(message.sid));
```

If this works, then that was the issue.

Otherwise could be `process.env.TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER` is not set correctly or `${appointment.meta.contact.number}` may be missing or invalid. Maybe print those also.

Twilio could also not have been correctly set up. Make sure `accountSid` and `authToken` are set.